# Discord.js specific timestap for code block

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, momentjs

[image]

How can I make such a time format?

Sample code I made:

```
.setDescription(` Your account was opened on ${moment(member.user.createdAt).startOf('day').fromNow()}.`)
```

I want to learn how to show the date of account establishment and server joining as in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord will convert any text in the format of `<t:SECONDS>` into a timestamp. Just replace `SECONDS` with the seconds since 12:00 am on January 1st, 1970 UTC (also known as the UNIX Epoch). Try this code:

```
.setDescription(` Your account was opened on <t:${moment(member.user.createdAt).unix()}>.`)
```

Note that the `.unix()` method in moment.js will return the seconds since the UNIX Epoch.

You can also check out [this website](https://discordtimestamp.com/) and play around with it to get the other formats, but in every format, the number you need is always the seconds since UNIX Epoch.